# M-RET and M-UP/DOWN not working in Emacs org-mode in console/terminal

Tags: emacs, terminal, emacs23, org-mode, terminator

I'm using `emacs23` on Ubuntu 32-bit 10.04/10.10 with GNOME and Compiz.

Pressing <kbd>M-RET</kbd> in an `org-mode` plain list in Emacs (GUI) inserts a new item. Pressing <kbd>M-Up</kbd> moves the item up in the list.

These keys don't work as expected in `emacs -nw` under Terminator and `gnome-terminal`. The <kbd>M-Up</kbd> key does nothing, whereas the <kbd>M-RET</kbd> key simply moves the cursor down one line and indents the position. The keys also don't "work" in `xterm`, which inserts `\215` instead. Pressing <kbd>ESC-RET</kbd> or <kbd>ESC-Up</kbd> instead produces the expected functionality. The same problems exist if I run `emacs -nw` on a headless server accessed via `ssh` under Terminator, `gnome-terminal` and `xterm`.

I've searched both generally and on the `org-mode` Gmane list for an answer to this, but have not found anything. Is this a known issue with `org-mode` or is it related to the terminal emulator and/or the Window Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the keys in my question, S-TAB, S-Left, S-Right, S-Up  and S-Down were not working over ssh and PuTTY. Using certain keys on a TTY connection (ssh, screen, PuTTY) is a known issue.

Alternative keys are included in org-mode as detailed in '[Using Org on a TTY](https://orgmode.org/manual/TTY-keys.html#TTY-keys)' in the org-mode manual.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative key combinations exist

for equivalent to M-RET
M C-m
 "`<return>`" is the Return ↩ key while emacs runs in a graphical user interface.

"RET" is the Return ↩ key while emacs runs in a terminal.

"RET" is also equivalent to "C-m" (【Ctrl+m】). (http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_key_notation_return_vs_RET.html)

as equivalents for M-`<up/down>` you can use

```
ESC-<up>
ESC-<down>
```

Answer (score 2):

The menubar of terminal emulator is not letting the `M` key that is meant for Emacs be passed down to Emacs.  For Emacs to receive the `M` key as it is supposed to, you could either use the `Esc` or disable the menubar and use `M` key in Emacs as usual.

ADDED:

For the xterm, if you do CTRL+Mouse Button 1, you will see "Meta sends Escape".  You need to make sure that option is checked/enabled to make `M` work as it should in Emacs.

Comment: @vpti3833: Thanks for the reply. How come `M-x` works in Emacs in Terminator/gnome-terminal? The `M` is getting through in this case. Disabling the menubar in gnome-terminal results in `M-UP` working, but not `M-RET`.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: `M-Ret` should be doing something in the terminal emulators, then.  In xterm it toggles between fullscreen and windowed display.  Not sure what it does in others, though.

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at the keyboard shortcuts in GNOME itself and in the emulators. `M-RET` is not bound to anything. I'll have to look into it further. I'll also try setting up `xterm` as you suggest.